# How to set up autocall macros on a 9.3 Unix server

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm using the enterprise version of SAS (v9.3) and want to set up some generic macros (for logging purposes) so that everyone in the department can use them.

I know what I want is the autocall functionality, but the only information I can find is for setting these up on a local install. Can anyone point me at some documentation on how to set these up on a (Unix) server?

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the SASAUTOS system option.  It's documented in the "SAS Companion for UNIX" here:  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/63053/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0uf2iszq5m4kin1qqpywhjwabpt.htm

The "safest" place to do this is in your system configuration file (sasv9_local.cfg in your SASHOME directory).

Comment: Thanks! I got it working by defining it as an option locally (options SASAUTOS='[path]';) If I wanted to affect all users, would I edit the usermods.cfg file in the SASMeta folder or SASApp or is there another one I've missed?

Comment: It depends on what you want done.  If you put this into the sasv9_local.cfg file in your SASHome directory, it will be in effect for all SAS processes on the machine.  If you only want this for certain BI services, put it in the appropriate usermods.cfg file (there might be several, depending on what you have installed).

Comment: Thanks Bob, I'll have a poke about on the server.